# add fo:marker marker-class-name="section.head.marker" to specific sections

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop, docbook

I have been trying to figure out how I can manually or automatically add the fo:marker section.head.marker to specific sections.

I am using FOP to convert my xml files to pdf.

My format looks as such

```
Article
    section A1 -
        section A2 -
            section A3
    section B1 -
        section B2 -
            section B3
```

I can use the

```
<xsl:param name="marker.section.level">3</xsl:param>
```

to generate the header for all of the sections, however i do not want the header to be generated for A3, but I do want it for B3.

I have tried switching A3 to a simplesect however simplesect at that level still has the header generated.

I have also tried manually adding the fo:marker as such:

```
<section id="B3">
    <fo:marker marker-class-name="section.head.marker">
        B3
    </fo:marker>
    <title id="B3.title">B3</title>
    ...
```

but in my pdf output i get:

```
<fo:marker> sensors </fo:marker>
```

Is there something that I am missing to manually add the fo:marker to my xml file, or is there a way to prevent fo:markers from being generated in simplesect's via xsl?

It looks like this might be solved in a similar way as

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('hard-pagebreak')">
    <fo:block break-after='page'/>
</xsl:template>
```

where instead of adding the hard-pagebreak command to the xml I add a header command of sorts that grabs the current section title and creates the fo:header

The xsl section that handles the running header generation is:

```
<xsl:param name="marker.section.level">2</xsl:param>
<xsl:template name="header.content">  
    <xsl:param name="position" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="sequence" select="''"/>

    <fo:block>
        <!-- position can be left, center, right -->
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$sequence = 'first'">
                <!-- off -->
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$position = 'left'">
                <xsl:call-template name="draft.text"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$position = 'center'">
                <fo:retrieve-marker 
                      retrieve-class-name="section.head.marker"
                      retrieve-position="first-including-carryover"
                      retrieve-boundary="page-sequence"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

The rest of my xsl file handles:

```
imports     <xsl:import href="./docbook-xsl/fo/docbook.xsl"/> first
moving TOC to new page
allowing hard page breaks
Adding footer ( title, page# )
verbatim segment properties
    shading/word wrap
formatting revision history
disable hyphenation
disable showing URLs of links
Color links
```

Comment: Unfortunately you may think you have asked a full question here, but you have only shown everyone only one half the story. No one can guess at what your current XSLs you are using to convert the XML data and therefore no answer can be given. You are asking us to guess at a completely unknown part of the picture ... the XSL that is processing the data.

Comment: @KevinBrown I updated the question to contain more information about the xsl file, and included the snippet that populates the center header feild with the running header information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to generate a manual section.head.marker with the following xsl code:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('running-header')">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:marker marker-class-name="section.head.marker">
            <xsl:value-of select="../title"/>
        </fo:marker>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

then I just included the running header processing-instruction.

```
<section id="B3"
     xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
     >
 <?running-header?>
<title id="B3.title">B3</title>
```

This allows me to manually add a section.head.marker with the current section title.